# Windows Azure Storage version upgrade to > 4 causes "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I started experiencing this after an upgrade to 4.0.1.0 via nuget package manager. I then upgraded to 4.1.0.0 hoping it may be a bug, but still same issue.

I am using the Cloud-based azure storage, NOT the emulator.

I was previously using 3.0.3.0 and it worked, and still works when I switch to this version.

This is the whole method (basically copying a blob from one container to another)

```
public string CopyBlobs(string blobPath)
    {
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(_storageAccountName, _storageAccountKey), true);
        var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var destContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(cloudBlobClient.BaseUri + _publishBlobContainer);

        destContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions(); 
        containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob; 
        destContainer.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);  
        var src = GetSasUrl(blobPath);
        CloudBlockBlob srcBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(src));
        CloudBlockBlob destBlob;
        destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(srcBlob.Name); 
        destBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(srcBlob);
        return destBlob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString();
    }
```

And this is where is throwing the exception:

```
destContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
```

UPDATE:
Fiddler logs when I call the method above.

Request:

```
HEAD       
https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/published-clips?restype=container HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WA-Storage/4.1.0 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.34014; Win32NT 6.2.9200.0)
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
x-ms-client-request-id: b60edc19-7d8f-4d6b-b264-0c98b9cb157d
x-ms-date: Thu, 26 Jun 2014 12:43:29 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey accountname:key
Host: accountname.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 85015e32-fdcf-4398-af23-83ddf8a27c1b
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-ms-request-id
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 26 Jun 2014 12:43:31 GMT
```

Comment: Is it possible to trace the request/response through Fiddler? That should give you more information about this 400 error.

Comment: @GauravMantri Added Fiddler request/response, but it doesn't say much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the following line of code:

```
var destContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(cloudBlobClient.BaseUri + _publishBlobContainer);
```

to

```
var destContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(_publishBlobContainer);
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! Backward compatibility concept anyone (from Microsoft)? :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no backward compatibility across major versions of the Storage Client Library. Note that each version is tied to a Storage Service REST version that could have changes in behavior (that's why we version both the service and client libraries). We recommend our customers to re-test their applications when upgrading to latest.

Thanks,
Jean

Answer (score 0):

To add, for future reference, we follow semantic versioning scheme for our sdk documented at [semver.org](http://semver.org/). You can use that as reference on what to expect for newer versions published.